# JAX-RS - Authentication and getting user data in RESTful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to RESTful Web Services and I'm trying to design my first secure web service using JAX-RS. But I have got this doubt.

Imagine I have a messenger API where I have a "/posts" web service, which would give me all the posts for the user who calls it. So I have designed a basic auth filter which does the authentication and if valid user, it passes the request to the /posts service which gives a list of posts for the user. Now the problem is the user in my DB has a user id which is not exposed to the user. Inside the /posts service I need the userId to get the posts of the requesting user. So my filter does the authentication and gets the userId for the logged in user.

My question is how to pass this userId to the /posts web service ?

My approach now is to add this userId as a request header info in the filter and then pass it to the /posts service.

But I am confused if this is the right approach to do it, or should this scenario be handled elegantly in some other way?

Please help me to understand what might be the best approach to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're considering creating your own security when there are already established standards that are well documented out there.  I've used OAuth and JWT tokens in the past to secure rest end points.  Depending on your specific requirements, you may be able to use Basic Authentication.

When it comes to security, it's rare that you'll be able to do a better job then the experts, so if you can follow a standard, you probably should.  The additional benefit being the next person to come a long has all the documentation and support to go along with it.

Update:

Just having the user ID in the request would not be sufficient. Anyone who knows someone else's user id would be able to spoof being that person and post to the endpoint as the other user.

"My question is how to pass this userId to the /posts web service ?"

Sessions can be used to store the internal user id.  If you already have them logged in with a session, you should be able to pull the user id from the session.  If you were to use JWT (which is stateless) you can pull whatever information you have stored in the token to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I have in mind about changing the authentication implementation to OAuth or a standard one. As the authentication is done in the filter, the service should not be bothered with what authentication mechanism is followed. My sole question is about how to pass the userid to the service. You mentioned to use sessions, but I have been reading that REST resources are stateless. How do I create a session, and if also I do is this a good practice? isn't that again a stateful one? Can you please provide a link for the JWT which you mentioned.. It can be useful.

Comment: https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/  https://jwt.io/   REST services can be stateless, it's also valid to have rest end points within a stateful application.  As for creating a session, that will entirely depend on the language you choose to implement your webservice in.  PHP has different session management than spring.  Cookies could also be an option.

Comment: Thanks for the link.